# Error building nodejs from source on Debian

Tags: debian, make, c++, g++

I keep getting the same error when running make on nodejs source code. I've looked and some common problems seem to be lack of a c compilier or install g++. I have these and have double checked.

Here is the last few lines showing the error:

```
../deps/v8/src/assembler.cc: In static member function 'static void v8::internal::ExternalReference::InitializeMathExpData()':
../deps/v8/src/assembler.cc:914:66: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/ccRCiDl6.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.
make[1]: *** [/home/labnosh/node-v0.12.7/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base/deps/v8/src/assembler.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/labnosh/node-v0.12.7/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
```

Comment: Does it always fail at the exact same point with the same error message or does it vary?

Comment: always. and ive tried several times

Comment: Then try upgrading your compiler. There's not much else you can do.

Comment: you mean g++ right?

Comment: An 'internal compiler error' is always a bug in the compiler itself and not within your code. You should indeed do as suggested by the message: submit a bug against gcc (and possibly check beforehand whether such exist). You can try older or newer gcc versions or another completely-different compiler and see whether you have success.